# Regex Pattern - Alphanumeric

Tags: c#, .net, regex

[username] where username is any string containing only alphanumeric chars between 1 and 12 characters long

My code:

```
Regex pat = new Regex(@"\[[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,12}\]");
MatchCollection matches = pat.Matches(accountFileData);
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    string username = m.Value.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
    MessageBox.Show(username);
}
```

Gives me one blank match

Comment: Watch your language.  How did it not work?

Comment: Why two sets of square brackets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gets you a name inside brackets (the match does't contain the square brackets symbol):

```
(?<=\[)[A-Za-z0-9]{1,12}(?=\])
```

You could use it like:

```
Regex pat = new Regex(@"(?<=\[)[A-Za-z0-9]{1,12}(?=\])");
MatchCollection matches = pat.Matches(accountFileData);
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    MessageBox.Show(m.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have too many brackets, and you may want to match the beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,12}$
```

If you are expecting square brackets in the string you are matching, then escape them with a backslash.

```
\[[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,12}\]

// In C#
new Regex(@"\[[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,12}\]")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have too many brackets.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{1, 12}
```

Comment: I need to keep the brackets too

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to match the brackets, they need to be escaped properly:

```
\[[a-zA-Z0-9]{1, 12}\]
```